# Inverse distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $F$ be a distribution function and $X$ a random variable which is uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,1)$. Let $F^{-1}$ be the inverse defined by $F^{-1}(y)=\inf\{x:F(x)\geq y\}$. How do I show that the random variable $Y=F^{-1}(X)$ has distribution function $F$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x\in(0,1)$.

$F^{-1}\left(x\right):=\inf\left\{ y\mid x\leq F\left(y\right)\right\} $
tells us directly that $x\leq F\left(y\right)\Rightarrow F^{-1}\left(x\right)\leq y$.

Since CDF $F$ is continuous from the right we also have $F^{-1}\left(x\right)\in\left\{ y\mid x\leq F\left(y\right)\right\} $.

This tells us that conversely $F^{-1}\left(x\right)\leq y\Rightarrow x\leq F\left(y\right)$.

So we have: $$F^{-1}\left(x\right)\leq y\iff x\leq F\left(y\right)$$ leading
to:

$$F^{-1}\left(X\right)\leq y\iff X\leq F\left(y\right)$$

and: $$P\left(F^{-1}\left(X\right)\leq y\right)=P\left(X\leq F\left(y\right)\right)=F\left(y\right)$$

Comment: Could you please explain 2 points: 1. Why "CDF F is continuous from the right" leads to $F^{-1}(x) \in $ {$  {y| x \leq F(y)}$} 2. Why this fact leads to the statement "This tells us that conversely $F^{-1}(x) \leq y \Rightarrow x \leq F(y)$". Thank you very much for your help! I'm struggling to understand this

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge For a fixed $x\in\left(0,1\right)$ let $A_{x}:=\left\{ y\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\leq F\left(y\right)\right\} $.
Then $A_{x}\neq\varnothing$ and $A_{x}\neq\mathbb{R}$ and $y\in A_{x}\implies\left[y,\infty\right)\subseteq A_{x}$
for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$. That leaves two options for $A_{x}$.
It must be of shape $\left[r,\infty\right)$ or of shape $\left(r,\infty\right)$
for some $r\in\mathbb{R}$. Here $r=\inf A_{x}$.

Comment: ....Now note that we
have $F\left(y\right)\geq x$ whenever $y>r$. That implies that $\lim_{y\downarrow r}F\left(y\right)\geq x$.
Here the monotonicity of $F$ ensures us that this limit exists. The
fact that $F$ is continuous from the right tells us that $\lim_{y\downarrow r}F\left(y\right)=F\left(r\right)$
so actually we found that $F\left(r\right)\geq x$ or equivalently
that $r\in A_{x}$. So it cannot be that $A_{x}=\left(r,\infty\right)$
and we conclude that $A_{x}=\left[r,\infty\right)$. Then $r\leq y\implies x\leq F\left(y\right)$. Finally be aware that $r=F^{-1}(x)$.